# Are there any cumulative axiomatizations of the numbers?

Tags: axioms, peano-axioms

By "cumulative axiomatization" I mean an axiomatization of the numbers where each set in the hierarchy of number types is explicitly a subset of the previous set. That is, $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$. All of the axiomatizations and constructions that I've seen have made each set of numbers an unrelated set, which violates my intuition that the naturals are (for example) a proper subset of the integers rather than isomorphic to a proper subset of the integers.

I'm thinking of an axiomatization that starts with the naturals, and then the first axiom in the axiomatization of the integers is $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{Z}$, and then so on for the other sets. Has there been any work in this area?

Comment: I like to think of these embeddings like this. We first define one smaller set A, then a bigger one B that we embed the first one in (i.e., via an isomorphism). But then, we can just think like "no, we have never actually worked with A, we have worked with prototype_of_A™ all along, the real A is that subset of B". That sure makes me sleep better. Either way, it doesn't matter as long as you can use the old and the new versions the same way

Comment: Elaborating a bit on what I said, when I was introduced in my class to the complex numbers, our teacher wanted to go full rigurosity and show us the construction. At the end she said "and we can just denote the pairs $(x, 0)$ as $x$" as if $x$ didn't already mean something. It's like everytime we had worked with real numbers up untill that point, we had worked  with a primitive version of them and the "complete" version is formed of pairs of that primitive version and $0$.

Comment: @StefanOctavian: I've never found that approach satisfying. One advantage of the Peano axioms is that they reflect an intuitive understanding of the natural numbers. If you are going to go through all that and then say, "that was just a fiction, the real natural numbers are just a tiny subset of this huge and much less intuitive structure", then what was the point of the Peano axioms in the first place? Such an approach goes against both history and intuition. And it's doubly odd if you are doing a construction where you need the Peano axioms to get started in the first place.

Comment: But in a sense we do that and have been doing that for ages: when we write out things like "$-2 + 3 = 1$", we say that $-2, 3, 1$ are all integers, treating $1$ and $3$ as the coercion to integer of the natural constructions of them and yet we still say, in the same context, that $1$ and $3 \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm not saying there couldn't be other (perhaps better) ways to see it, I'm saying IMHO that this is the way of seeing it that makes me feel the most at ease and that I could make the most sense of.

Comment: Natural vs Integers is quite simple: start from the axioms for Integers and introduce the definition: for every z, Natural(z) iff $z \ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

After a long time, I came back to this question because I found a way to axiomatize numbers in a cumulative manner and I really don't see anything wrong with it, it actually seems to me like a good way to axiomatize extensions.

Generally, we start from some set $A$ with some structure attached and we want to extend it to another set $B$ with a 'larger' structure. We do this via an embedding, $A \hookrightarrow B$, ie. an injective homomorphism from $A$ onto some subset $E$ of $B$ (which has a substructure inherited from $B$'s structure). Via this embedding we identify the elements of $E$ with the elements of $A$ and effectively consider $A$ as a subset of $B$. What this means is up to discussion in my opinion and one way to see it is how I put it in the comments. But now I want to show another way to see it:

Instead of 'rewriting history' and changing what we mean by the set $A$, why not change $B$? We are still constructing it, so, why not go through 2 versions of it?

Say we have found a set $B_{\beta}$ such that $A \overset{\varphi}{\longleftrightarrow} E \subset B_{\beta}$. We'll suppose $A \cap B_{\beta} = \varnothing$. We can just replace $E$ in $B_{\beta}$ with $A$. Define the following conversions: $\beta : A \cup B_{\beta} \to B_{\beta},\ \beta(x) = \varphi(x)$ if $x\in A$ and $\beta(x) = x$ if $x\in B_{\beta}$,
$\alpha : B_{\beta} \to A \cup B_{\beta},\ \alpha(x) = \varphi^{-1}(x)$ if $x \in E$ and $\alpha(x) = x$ otherwise.

Now we can 'upgrade' from the `beta` version to the `alpha` version: define $B = A \cup (B_{\beta}\setminus E)$. Using the conversions above, we can translate the structure of $B_{\beta}$ to the desired structure of $B$ that is compatible with the one of $A$. For example, if $B_{\beta}$ is a group with some operation $\circ$, define the operation $\circ$ on $B$ as $x \circ y = \alpha(\beta(x) \circ \beta(y))$. You can verify that $(B, \circ)$ is indeed a group and that $(A, \circ)$ is a subgroup of it.

This way, we can define the integers as "all the natural numbers with their usual rules and also an additional set of numbers $-n$ for every non-zero natural number $n$" after seeing that pairs of the form $(\pm, n)$ and $0$ hold for our purposes and we can embed the natural numbers into this structure.

Comment: Yes, you're simply replacing the isomorphic copy with the real thing, and redefining the operations accordingly. This is completely standard, so there is indeed nothing wrong with it. It's unfortunate that people who teach the constructions ℕ → ℤ → ℚ → ℝ often don't teach it properly. By the way, I'll avoid using the word "embed"in your last sentence because it doesn't mean what you want, which is literal inclusion. An embedding of a structure S into another structure T is simply an isomorphism from S into T. You have explained how we can get from embedding to inclusion.

Comment: Well, yes, that's precisely what I wanted to say in the last sentence. I mean that, after seeing that the pairs hold for our purpose of extending the naturals and we can indeed embed the naturals into the set of the the pairs and 0, we can then pass from embedding to inclusion as described.

Comment: I was hinting that you should edit your answer to change "embed" to "make ... actually a substructure of". =)

Comment: Please, read my response comment again. This is a misunderstanding. The last sentence as I wrote is exactly what I meant to say. I actually mean "embed" there, not inclusion. Inclusion is intuitively mentioned in the first part of the sentence, but in the last part, what I mean is definitely embedding, as in, we must first verify that an embedding is possible before passing to inclusion.

Comment: the last part of the last sentence read as "after seeing that ... and *that* we can embed"

Comment: Ok so you meant an implicit "that"... it would be clearer if you had put that "that" in, but since you're clarified in the comments it's fine!